# Vue.js - pass template to grandchild

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that defines a set of slots dynamically from props like this:

```
<template v-for="(field, index) in fields">
  <div
    v-if="!field.hide"
    :key="index"
    class="my-class"
  >
    <slot :name="getSlotName(field.name, 'label')" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And I have a component `WrapperComponent` that uses template to fill those slots:

```
<slotted-component :fields="[{name: 'f1'}]">
  <template #f1>
    Some content here
  </template>
</slotted-component>
```

And I want to be able to override the content of <template #f1> from the parent component of the  `WrapperComponent` like

```
<WrapperComponent>
  <template #f1>
    Some other content
  </template>
</WrapperComponent>
```

I tried to use a `PassThroughTemplate` component with this template:

```
<template>
  <template v-slot:[name]>
    <slot
      :name="name"
      v-bind="$attrs"
    />
  </template>
</template>
```

but it gives me a compilation error if not compiling at runtime (only eslint yells in this case). I want to use render function, but this code doesn't render anything:

```
render (h, ctx) {
  return h(
    'template',
    {slot: ctx.props.name},
    h('slot', {name: ctx.props.name})
  )
}
```

and i don't know how to use it properly. So, is there a way to do that or another way to achieve template replacement?

Comment: I've never seen 'v-for' directives on a ```<template>``` tag.  TBH, this all looks a bit confusing to me (perhaps I'm easily confused).  If you know the content of your 'override' templates ahead of time, I would consider creating separate child components out of those templates, which could then be included with 'v-if' when logical.  And if   you are new to Vue, do as many tutorials as possible to get comfortable with the tech.  And I recommend learning the Vue CLI as well.

Comment: That's the problem - I don't know what content will be rendered. I'm not new to vue and don't know how vue cli would help, tbh.